# Splitting list into rows

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with two columns. One column is ‘Exchange’ and the other is ‘StartToEnd’. I had the issue that each row in the exchange column would contain more than one exchange name. So like:

```
London Stock Exchange Berlin Stock Exchange
```

However python would read that as 1 string so I used str.split and it made each row into a list so now each row looks like:

```
['London Stock Exchange', 'Berlin Stock Exchange']
```

How could I split that one row into two individual rows but also duplicate the StartToEnd value for both new rows. So it would look like:

```
Exchange.               StartToEnd
London Stock Exchange.    15.4
Berlin Stock Exchange.    15.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) for this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ "Exchange" : [['London Stock Exchange', 'Berlin Stock Exchange']], 'StartToEnd': [15.4]  })

df[["London","Berlin"]] = pd.DataFrame(df.Exchange.tolist())
df = df.drop('Exchange', axis=1)

df.melt(id_vars = ["StartToEnd"], value_name = 'Exchange').drop('variable',axis=1)
```

yields:

```
    StartToEnd  Exchange
0   15.4    London Stock Exchange
1   15.4    Berlin Stock Exchange
```